# GetHostByName error with http link to get IP address

Tags: c#, .net

Hi
I have a requirement where extract the IP from URL. The following code is working in one case:

```
string str2 = "www.google.com";
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostByName(str2);
IPAddress [] IpA = ip.AddressList;
for (int i = 0; i < IpA.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, IpA[i].ToString ());
}
```

But if change the URL as

```
string str2 = "http://google.com";
```

`GetHostByName` is throwing exception.

What method I should use which work in both cases?

Comment: Depend on the answer's i got.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` method to determine whether the `str2` is well-formed and then get the host only:

```
string str2 = "http://www.google.com";
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(str2, UriKind.Absolute))
{
    str2 = new Uri(str2).Host;
}
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(str2);
```

also MSDN says that `Dns.GetHostByName` is obsolete, and you should use `Dns.GetHostEntry` instead.